# PHP - Form, post to same page, error handling, prevent resubmission

Tags: php, forms, post, error-handling

I have come across quite the problem when making my own framework. I have found some other questions that come close to what I'm asking, but not quite.

This is what I am attempting:

- Page has a form with method post and submits to itself (same page).
- When you submit, the input is validated appropriate messages / errors
  are displayed.

It seems simple, but I am trying to:

- Avoid form resubmission that comes with using post. This wouldn't be
  a problem if I also wasn't trying to...
- Avoid having duplication or more code than needed. Redirection adds an extra action where I would need to check the input twice (once on the submit page for validation and once on the redirected page for messages/ errors).
- Avoid using query strings, cookies or sessions. Which makes the
  solution of posting to another page and then redirecting while still having message handling impossible
  (as far as I know).
- Avoid relying on AJAX since JS can be disabled.

Am I asking too much or is there a way to do this? Is there something I would need to compromise on to achieve this? If not, then I guess I will go with sessions and redirection.

Comment: Randomly generate a unique key and submit that with the form.  Check the db for that key before doing a final commit.  Even if the user refreshes the page, the initial submit will be there.

Comment: Hmm that would seems like it would work. Out of curiosity, is there a standard for post forms? I see a lot of things on redirecting.

Comment: It's not really a lot of extra work.  You generate the key when the page loads the first time. No need for Javascript.  Then when the page submits, you simply check it all out in the db before committing it.  As far as a standard goes...  Not really.  Best practices, perhaps.  But everybody has different ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure i understood well, do you need to process $_POST on the same page, which holds the form and avoid re-sending the data?

if so, u need to reload page, without POST after proceeding your form ...
i.e.

```
 if(isset($_POST["YOUR_FORM_FIELD"])){
   header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
   exit();
 }
```

BUT - reloading is in conflict with your request to not use _SESSION, or _GET nad send a message to be displayed. i did not find a way how to pass a variable through HTTP headers - which seems to me like the only way ...

anyway i do recommend to consider using _SESSION ....

Comment: Yes you understood what I was asking. I think you might be right about the post. I will try to see how durbnpoisn's idea works out and I think using sessions is the only alternate option.

Comment: the idea seems to be working fine - BUT :D - when reloading page you'll be forced to confirm the POST re-sending dialog ... which i do consider as trully disturbing ...

if you'll compare GET and SESSION, please take on mind GET has much more limited amount of data, which can be processed that way ...

Comment: I ended up doing it with short lived session variables and redirection with header like you mentionned. The get was limiting, the form resubmission was is not very pleasant for users and I managed to cleanly divide my code after all. Thank you!